# Convert PHP while loop to use PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm currently updating my app by switching to PDO. I have the following code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from `product` where productid in (:productidLst)");
$stmt->bindParam(":productidLst",$productidLst, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

The var $productidLst is 1,2 after the above code I would like to use the PDO equivalent of this:

```
while($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $rs['qty']=$_SESSION['basket'][$rs['productid']];
    $rs['total'] += $rs['qty']*$rs['price'];
    $total += $rs['total'];
    $a[] = $rs;
}
```

I have tried numerous combinations but not been successful so any help with this would be appreciated (in the 2nd code block $res was the sql). Secondly I have set the Parameter $productidLst to INT is this correct or should it be a string?

--------------------UPDATE 1----------------------------------------------------

I have tried the following code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from `product` where productid in (:productidLst)");
foreach ($stmt->execute(array(':productidLst' => $productidLst)) as $row) 
{
    $total += $row['total'];
}
```

Which returns:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error

Comment: At this point, you can't bind a [list value to a query parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition).

Comment: `PDOStatement::execute()` returns a boolean which is not suitable for use in `foreach`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The standard documentation in the PHP manual is usually pretty helpful.  There is an example of executing a for loop with PDO in the PHP manual, [PDO Details](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).

```
function getFruit($conn) {
    $sql = 'SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit ORDER BY name';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['name'] . "\t";
        print $row['color'] . "\t";
        print $row['calories'] . "\n";
    }
}
```

With a few changes, the example can be made to use a prepared statement.

```
function getFruit($conn) {
    $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit WHERE kind=:kind ORDER BY name');
    $query->execute(array(':kind' => 'drupe'));
    // alternatively you could use PDOStatement::fetchAll() and get rid of the loop
    // this is dependent upon the design of your app
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        print $row['name'] . "\t";
        print $row['color'] . "\t";
        print $row['calories'] . "\n";
    }
}
```

You can also use a `while` loop and [`PDOStatement::fetch`](http://php.net/PDOStatement.fetch) to get each row.

```
function getFruit($conn) {
    $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit WHERE kind=:kind ORDER BY name');
    $query->execute(array(':kind' => 'drupe'));
    // alternatively you could use PDOStatement::fetchAll() and get rid of the loop
    // this is dependent upon the design of your app
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        print $row['name'] . "\t";
        print $row['color'] . "\t";
        print $row['calories'] . "\n";
    }
}
```

The PHP manual remains quite helpful in providing all the necessary information to create the latter two versions.

Explanation of the last version: assuming `$conn` is a valid PDO object.  `$conn->prepare($sql)` returns a [`PDOStatement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object if successful, `false` on failure *OR* an exception based on your error handling.  So, assuming success we would want to actually get the data from the object.  We can use [`$query->fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) in a loop or [`$query->fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to get the data dependent upon your app.  Passing in the class constant `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` will return, you guessed it, an associative array of data.

Functionally, the `foreach` and `while` implementations are equivalent. Conceptually, a `foreach` is more appropriate, as a `while` loop has connotations of looping while a static condition holds, whereas `foreach` loops over elements of a collection. Read "[Differences between a while loop and a for loop in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698935/differences-between-a-while-loop-and-a-for-loop-in-php/2699003#2699003)" for part of the story.

Be sure to read the [php.net reference on PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Hi thanks for the responses, 

I am still struggling, I keep getting : Invalid argument supplied for foreach():. Please see orginal post under update 1 section for the code that I am using. (Note I slightly simplified the code within the while loop for ease of reading)

Comment: @outis I just edited it myself with the appropriate code changes and an explanation.

Comment: @Charles: how was the earlier code edit inappropriate? `PDOStatement` implements `Traversable`, and the default fetch mode is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`. Rob's point was that the PHP manual has an example that basically answers Dino's question. Switching from a `foreach` to a `while` detracts from this point.

Comment: @outis That was my mistake, I was not aware that `PDOStatement` was `Traversable`.  If you want, you can revert my edit.  I personally like this approach better, but to each their own.  Thanks for the info about `Traversable` though.

Comment: @Charles: let's combine the two.

Comment: @outis Looks good.  I'm sure it will be quite helpful for those of us, including myself, who have only ever seen PDOStatements used with a `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) to fetch the row. It fetches (by default) both numerically and associatively. You can change that as well.

With your code:

```
while($rs=$stmt->fetch()){
    $rs['qty']=$_SESSION['basket'][$rs['productid']];
    $rs['total'] += $rs['qty']*$rs['price'];
    $total += $rs['total'];
    $a[] = $rs;
}
```

**[Manual Reference](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)**.