# Pass multiple parameters in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My PHP looks like this:

```
$diagSel = $_POST['diagSel'];
$search_crit = $_POST['criteria']; //this is an entry like "85054,85206" (no quotes)
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` where`Diagnosis` = :diagnosis and `zip_code` in (:placeHolder) group by `Provider Number`";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
$stmt->bindParam(':diagnosis', $diagSel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':placeHolder', $search_crit, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result1 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result1);
```

Here's the problem...if the user enters multiple ZIP Codes (passed in `criteria`) that are comma separated, this `ECHO`s nothing. If they enter a single ZIP Code, it returns exactly what I'd expect.

Is there a way to pass a comma separated value by PDO such as 85054,85206 using prepared statements?

Thanks.

Comment: Use an ORM or PDO wrapper that supports array binding (Aura.SQL does, others allow Perl-style `??` list placeholders). Alternatively: use `FIND_IN_SET()` for a CSV list.

Comment: Haven't used the `??` methods much before...can you give an example?

Comment: That's not a PDO thing. This requires an abstraction library on top which allows such placeholders. Else you'll have to resort to [hodgepodge `join()`/etc. workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not, I'd recommend something like this:

```
$diagSel     = $_POST['diagSel'];
$search_crit = $_POST['criteria'];
$list        = explode(',', $search_crit);
array_map(array($dbh, 'quote'), $list);

$sql1 = sprintf('
  SELECT *
  FROM `myTable`
  WHERE `Diagnosis` = :diagnosis
  AND `zip_code` IN (%s)
  GROUP BY `Provider Number`', implode(',', $list));

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
$stmt->bindParam(':diagnosis', $diagSel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$result1 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result1);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is something missing from this line? `array_map([$dbh, 'quote'], $list);` Getting error: `Call to undefined function sprtinf()`

Comment: Actually...missed one thing...getting this error now though: `syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'` This is referring to the `array_map` line.

Comment: Sorry the first one was a typo, the second I believe you have an old version of PHP (pre 5.4). Try now!

Comment: I thought I was on PHP 5.4, but maybe not. I tried the above and now getting this error: " Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number'" referring to the `execute` line

Comment: Nevermind...missed the `(%s)` in the query. It's working perfectly! Thanks for the help.

Comment: One more question...this works perfectly when I pass in numbers like ZIP codes (45642,23245), but if I try to do it with states that are strings like (NY,AK), then it doesn't work. It seems like I need to add double quotes around each state name in the query to get it to work, but not sure how this would be done or if there's another alternative.

Comment: No...different query, but same idea. Replace `zip_code` with `state`. They are stored in different columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use bindpram twice if you want to add multiple values to the SQL query have an array in the exec command to add in all the variables

Comment: Okay...any suggestions on an alternative way to do this?

Comment: $shtm->execute(array(
 ':diagnosis' => $diagSel,
 ':placeHolder' => $search_crit
 ));     <-- Like that

Comment: Thanks...this has me back where I started. If I pass one ZIP code, it works fine. If I pass multiple, it doesn't work (`ECHO`s nothing)

Comment: Use a while loop to return all results

Comment: Sorry...a bit of a noob here with PHP...can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043456/convert-php-while-loop-to-use-pdo sorry but I am in a tight time situation this link will show you how to iterate though the results