# What's the difference between while() and for()?

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

Maybe my question seems primary, But actually it is not. I claim that I can do **everything** is done with `for()` by `while()`, And conversely. So really when `while()` is useful when there is `for()`? I need to a example that I can do that by `for()` and I can not do that by `while()`. There is? I think there is not ...!

Here is the structure:

```
for (init counter; test counter; increment counter) {
    code to be executed;
}


init counter;
while (test counter) {
    code to be executed;
    increment counter;
}
```

see? they are exactly the same, Now I want to know why *php* has both of them?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2698935/3933332

Comment: Yes!!! i think there is a one difference. If you know the number of iteration go for For loop otherwise While loop. And one more thing For loop is more readable and precise manner

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is that the do while loop executes at least once because it checks for the loop condition while exiting. While is a entry controlled loop and do while is a exit control loop. Whereas in do while loop it will enter the loop and will then check for the condition.

**while loop** - used for looping until a condition is satisfied and when it is unsure how many times the code should be in loop

**for loop** - used for looping until a condition is satisfied but it is used when you know how many times the code needs to be in loop

**do while loop** -  executes the content of the loop once before checking the condition of the while.

Comment: Please, fill the difference between `while{}` and `do{}while`

Answer (score 0):

They are exactly the same :

### WHILE

```
INITIALIZE_1;
INITIALIZE_2;
...
INITIALIZE_N;
while(CONDITIONS) {
    // your block code
    ...
    # not only incrementation !!
    OPERATION_1;
    OPERATION_2;
    ...
    OPERATION_N;
}
```

### FOR

```
for (INITIALIZE_1, INITIALIZE_2, ..., INITIALIZE_N ; CONDITIONS ; OPERATION_1, OPERATION_2, ..., OPERATION_N) {
    // your block code
    ...
}
```

`for` is more comprehensive for a humain, so he can see in one line : the initialization, conditions and operations, but there are other cases when `while` is more appropriate like :

```
while(NOT_QUIT_SIGNAL) { ... } vs for ( ; NOT_QUIT_SIGNAL ; ) { ... }
```

or

```
while(TRUE) { ... } vs for ( ; TRUE ; ) { ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while(true)` for a daemon (although there are definitely better languages for it), or a similar scenario, where you may want the script to run indefinitely.

Alternatively, while can be used with a predicate, or executing a function each time to check for a property.

```
while(functionCanExecute($someVar)) {
    //Do Stuff
}
```

This will be evaluated initially, and after every loop, to check if the while loop should run again.

Their underlying functionality may be very similar/the same, but there are certainly scenarios when it's easier to use one over the other.