# What exactly is the difference between for, while, and do while loops? And in which example case scenarios should I use each?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I'm a JS  beginner and am having trouble understanding the difference between these types of loops.
I have a general grip over `for` loops, which I have been using for some time, but I've never used the other two. I understand that `do while` loops execute at least one time, then check if the condition is true. However, I don't get what's the difference between `for` and `while` loops. Maybe someone could show me some case scenarios in which each one is best?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between while() and for()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562212/whats-the-difference-between-while-and-for) - while marked as a duplicate for PHP, the accepted answer seems to answer your question.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, I checked the accepted answer on that question and it helped! Thank you so much. Should I delete this question altogether or marked it as solved?